# Getting error from php what did I do wrong?

Tags: php

So I get the following error.

> [02-Nov-2015 16:29:48 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning: 
>   number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\handpaytest\index.php on line 17

This the code that its complaining about.

```
echo "<td>Past Week:   $" . number_format(htmlspecialchars($cell)) . "</td>";
```

In context

```
<div id='Title'></div>
    <div id='week'> 
        <?php 
            echo "<center><table>\n\n";

            $f = fopen("week.csv", "r");
            while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach ($line as $cell) {
                            echo "<td>Past Week:   $" . number_format(htmlspecialchars($cell)) . "</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            fclose($f);
            echo "\n</center></table>";
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: As Dagon said above ^, what is `$cell`?

Comment: do Google your error; many hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) does is  **Convert special characters to HTML entities**

So, you need to [Type caste](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/type-casting-variables-in-php-is-there-a-practical-example) `$cell` as `(float)$cell` before passing it to 
[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
number_format((float)$cell)
```

Comment: $cell just contains a number value that its grabbing from a csv file.  Thanks! This was the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As we don't know what $cell contains, You can try to force its type to be float.

```
echo "<td>Past Week:   $" . number_format((float)$cell)) . "</td>";
```